# Creating tables - int in quotes?

Tags: sql-server-2008, int

When I create a table and I am putting an int, is this ok:

```
insert into Employee_T
(Emp_Id)
values
(
'100' /*WILL THERE BE A PROBLEM IF I PUT IT LIKE THIS, IE WITH THE QUOTES*/? 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly valid, but entirely unnecessary, to put an integer literal in quotes.

It will be parsed as a string and automatically converted to an integer.

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/464db/1)

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for the help and that link. I like that it has many DB in one place.

Answer (score 1):

No problem: the string literal will be CAST to int on insertion.

I wouldn't normally do it myself because it is misleading though...

Answer (score 1):

No,

this should work just fine.
The sql server will the parse the string and convert it into a integer.
Of course this is not optimal for performance,
and it also can cause problems if some formatting like 1.000 or 12,000 is in the string...

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a problem. I mean, it won't cause an error. Maybe there is just a little performance overhead of converting the types. It's little but unnecessary and may show up on high load.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are used in case the type is `char` or `varchar`. If you are using `int` then there is no need to give quotes for inserting the values. You should use the following query:-

```
insert into Employee_T (Emp_Id) values (100);
```

However, the SQLServer support quotes also for `int`. But its a good practice if you are not using quotes for `int`.